# Video continues to play after being hidden in jQuery

Tags: jquery, video

I've got a drop down menu which when selected displays a different video for each option. The problem is that if you start watching a video then decide to pick another, the first video will continue to play in the background even though you can't see it resulting in two audio tracks playing at the same time.

The page is [here](http://apexhubmobile.co.uk/coach_drop.php)  and it relies on [this](http://apexhubmobile.co.uk/scripts/apex.min.js) script to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pause the video using the javascript `pause()` method from your players [api](http://wistia.com/doc/player-api#player_api_methods)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the general direction, but I still can't finish the thing off for myself! I added the Wistia script to my footer like the site suggests but then I am a bit lost as to what code to add where. I gave all the videos a class of .cdd and I've tried adding `jQuery(".cdd")[0].wistiaApi.pause();` to the change event in apex.min.js but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I had called the script on the wrong page! Fixed now.